# How do you get the actual height of the DropDownList attached to a ComboBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I want to get the actual height of the ComboBox plus the height of its DropDown when it is opened. However there does not appear to be an accessible property  on the ComboBox to give this.

The **ComboBox.ActualHeight** property only gives the height of the base ComboBox, not its dropdown.

This one is kind of infuriating as I think I can see the value set on a property in the debugger, but the property is not accessible in code for some reason - **ItemsHost.ActualHeight**.

See below:

[image: ActualHeight is accessible]

However, ItemsHost which appears to have the height of the dropdown is not accessible from code!

[image]

Comment: Not sure why it is not accessible but try getting height of one item * number of items + height of combobox

Comment: As it happens that is what I am doing for now! It works but is not pixel perfect. The ComboBox is slightly higher than the Items in the drop down.

Comment: As it happens I was able to deduct the Padding top and bottom of the ActualHeight to get an accurate estimation of the height of each item in the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is not accessible because it is not defined as `public`. You *could* get its value using reflection:

[Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

You shouldn't really do this though as the property is non-public for a reason.

Instead, you could get a reference to the `Popup` element of the `ComboBox` and check the `ActualHeight` property of its `Child`, e.g.:

```
ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
double heightOfComboBox = cmb.ActualHeight;

double heightOfPopup = 0.0;
Popup popup = cmb.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", cmb) as Popup;
if (popup != null)
{
    FrameworkElement fe = popup.Child as FrameworkElement;
    if (fe != null)
        heightOfPopup = fe.ActualHeight;
}

double totalHeight = heightOfComboBox + heightOfPopup;
```

Comment: Don't worry I did upvote! But I don't have enough reputation for it to register sadly. EDIT - Looks like I do since yesterday, have my upvote!!